# Best practice to create topics in dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, architecture, confluent-platform

I'm just started working with Kafka together with C# (dotnet core). I have spinnned up an Kafka environment with Schema Registry using docker (Confluent Images).

I have a hobby project where I try to implement a microservice architecture. I will use Kafka to handle my IntegrationEvents between services.

Right now I have created my Kafka topics through the Confluent UI but I really like to have configuration as code - etc. I have database migrations using EF Core Migrations - Cloud environment using TerraForm.

What would be the best practices for creating topics? Right now I am thinking to create topics when my applications is starting up (if it exists it does nothing). The responsible application for creating the topic will be the application that needs to produce to that topic.

Any input our ideas what I can improve or do I have missed something that can potentiel cause me a lot of troubles.

Best regards Martin

Comment: AdminClient exists in the dotnet confluent package... Works fine. Terraform providers also exist for Kafka

Comment: I am aware of the AdminClient. It was more about when and where. My thought is to write a reusable service that can create topics with configuration and do it on application startup when bootstrapping the API of application - but I was interested in knowing what people are doing and what their experience is.

Comment: Spring-Kafka and a few other Java frameworks do do this with their config objects. I've also seen Kubernetes Operators create topics, or Jenkins, or Terraform as mentioned... All depends what tools you have available, AFAIK, there is no high-level config library for dotnet that would provide such a feature out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to just use a command for my docker compose file. I still don't know or have decided for how my hosting environment will be. So wether going with Kubernetes all the way or using only Azure Services or ConfluentCloud.

So on I will postpone my decision regarding that and when time comes I will adjust code or Terraform for that.